# Why this css style is not working in IE 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLKQb/1/)**.

It works fine in `Firefox` and `chrome`, but with my `IE 8`, it looks like below:
[image]

Could anyone tell me what's wrong so that it is incompatible with `IE 8`? Thanks!

Comment: gradient and round corners don't work in old things ;)

Comment: I fixed.. i mean old ;) i just woke up lol but if you can try modernizer... or something apache hack to make the corners in EI8

Comment: Pardon me, I'm new to css. `IE 8` is old thing? If so, what's the alternative for gradient and round? Thanks~@jycr753

Comment: even IE9 is pretty ancient as CSS support goes.  current IE is 11.

Comment: In addition, you're only using the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes for some styles. You could guess that won't work in other browsers. At least include the unprefixed version as well.

Comment: @EEvee The problem is that IE8 is the last version that works on Windows XP, and many people are unwilling to give up XP.

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, and Opera work just fine on XP

Comment: also fyi, `-moz-border-radius` and `-moz-box-shadow` haven't worked in Firefox for a while now.

Comment: I just ctrl-CV some effect to my .css file, as I said, I'm really new to css :>, so is there any place where I can search for the equality to `-moz-` or `-webkit`? Thanks bro~ @MrLister

Comment: caniuse.com lists which prefixes are required for which versions, but you should **always** include an unprefixed rule for finalized CSS properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red bits on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) may provide a hint.

I can't speak for it personally, but [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) promises to make border-radius, linear-gradient, and some other CSS3 properties work in IE8 via some dark magic.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it to a general one.